# Шаблоны joomla для портфолио

Tags: joomla, php

Какой сайт крупный можете посоветовать по шаблонам joomla, в частности шаблоны для портфолио? А то искал, сайта 3 нашёл, но там выбор очень маленький(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Ищите](http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=joomla+templates&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest#pq=joomla+templates&hl=en&sugexp=kjrmc&cp=3&gs_id=i&xhr=t&q=free+joomla+templates&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&client=opera&hs=ZNq&rls=en&channel=suggest&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=frejoomla+templates&aq=0c&aqi=g-c4&aql=f&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=13eef5d7cca4f784&biw=1280&bih=864) по-английски. Найдете [вполне приличные](http://www.getjoomlatemplatesfree.com/free-template/Platine-45-Free-Joomla-Theme.html) [варианты](http://www.joomla24.com/) с [симпатичными](http://www.siteground.com/template-preview/joomla_15/siteground-j15-179) галерейками.
2. Постарайтесь пересмотреть движок. По возможности, используйте что-то более шустрое и легкое для такой [простой задачи](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/). Можно просто [скрипт галереи](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/18/30-best-solutions-for-image-galleries-slideshows-lightboxes/) установить.
3. Если портфолио - список веб-проектов, которые вы осуществили, настоятельно рекомендую [написать свой](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) движок.

Comment: Плюсую п.2. Я всегда плюсую совет пересмотреть выбор джумлы. Я добрый)

Comment: Разные бывают ситуации. Иногда люди с джумлы переходят на юкоз. *facepalm*

Comment: Спасибо. Да мне только дизайн нужен, я его немного подредактирую и натяну на свой сайт.
Sh4dow, чем вам не нравится джумала?

Comment: А зачем тогда уточнение, что для джумлы? `*`**mistrust**`*` В мире существуют и другие халявные дизайны, честное слово, [Песец][1] не даст соврать.


  [1]:http://hashcode.ru/users/465/sh4dow

Comment: Потому что всю жизнь работаю с джумолой и вордпрессом. Для джумлы шаблон хочу, потому что, возможно, всё-таки буду с ней работать. Ещё не решил, как время будет. Но раз ты советуешь всё-таки свой сайт, то наверно свой и сделаю.

Answer (score 1):

Советую мой [любимый](http://www.joomla24.com/.)

А что касается выбора движка, да в ряде случаев Джумла- не айс.

Но, если портфолио вы делаете для заработка, то, на готовом шаблоне и Джумле, можно за полдня развернуть сайт и "загнать" фото с описаниями.
А остальное время посвятить поиску заказчиков и выполнению оплачиваемой работы. Заказчику по барабану, на чем ваш сайт- главное, чтобы ему нравилось.

Знаете, не знаю, для чего именно вам нужно портфолио, но если для заработка, то вы уверены, что тот клиент, для которого время загрузки джумлы принципиально- именно ваш клиент?
Если уж делать совсем просто, то модно просто сделать html-файл, накидать фото, добавить подписей, с каким-нибудь простеньким [эффектом](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/simplegallery.htm).

Еще играет роль количество фотографий. Если их с десяток- да, проще самому. Если значительно больше, да еще и все по разделам раскидать...